# Get Label text-value from Listview label in C#

Tags: c#, listview

**C#**

```
protected void imgbtn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["theme"] = lbl5.Text;
    foreach (ListViewItem item in theme5.Items)
    {
        Label country = (Label)item.FindControl("lblcountry");
        Session["country"] = country.ToString();        
        Label price = (Label)item.FindControl("lblprice");
        Session["price"] = price.ToString();         
    }       
}
```

Here because of foreach Session Values get null again.
please suggest some other way.

**aspx**

```
<asp:ListView ID="theme5" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblcountry" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Country") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Here i want to get my label text value and transfer it to a session.
I guess there is problem with:

```
Label country = (Label)theme5.FindControl("lblcountry");
```

Here in country i get null value found while dubugging.

Comment: Hi Rick, Maybe you can supply us with some more infromation. What is theme5? and what are you trying to do exactly. Isn't it possible to just say var country = lblcountry.Text then your country is a string but you only want to have the text to the session and not the whole Label. Slap in the face for me i see the theme5 is a ListView sorry :)

Comment: doesn't 

protected void imgbtn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           Session["country"] = lblcountry.Text;
    }

work?

why are you using the FindControl method, are you trying to access something from a Master or what's happening?

Comment: I have a lable in listview.
And theme5 is the name of listview.
i want to capture the label value and transfer it in session

Comment: Rick, are you sure that '<%#Eval("Country") %>' is not null?

Comment: @tranceporter Yes m sure <%#Eval("Country") %> is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you are adding label instead of label text**

```
protected void imgbtn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["theme"] = lbl5.Text;
    foreach (ListViewItem item in theme5.Items)
    {
        Label country = (Label)item.FindControl("lblcountry");
// here insted of country.ToString() you Should use 
        Session["country"] = country.Text.ToString();        
        Label price = (Label)item.FindControl("lblprice");
        Session["price"] = price.Text.ToString();         
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
var index = ...;

var result = (label)theme5.Items[index].FindControl("lblcountry");
```

You can use this code based on `Itemcommand`

```
<asp:ListView ID="theme5" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btn"
    Text="..."
    CommandName="YourCommand"
    CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'
    runat="server"   ItemCommand="Test_ItemCommand" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>



protected void Test_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

 if (e.CommandName.Equals("YourCommand"))
 {
      var result = (label)theme5.Items[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].FindControl("lblcountry"); 
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to access the currently selected item of theme5 and get the Label in that item:

```
Label lblcountry = 
  (Label)theme5.Items[theme5.SelectedIndex].FindControl("lblcountry");
```

Comment: I got this error after using above code :

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index